# 2018 tax refund applied to 2019 estimated tax

Tags: united-states, taxes, irs, refund

For 2018 Fed tax refund, I elected applied it to 2019 estimated tax. Internet said it need to be applied to 2019 1st quarter by 4/15.? But I missed this date. Can I apply it to the 2nd and 3rd quarter? If so, how can I process it? I use www.eftps.gov to make online payment quarterly. Just simply minus the refund from my regular payment amount? Do I need to fill out any related form?

Comment: When did you file your 2018 tax return (if you mailed a paper copy) or when was your tax return accepted by IRS (if you filed electronically)?

Comment: My CPA filed electronically for me around 4/10/2018. I always asked for refund in mail, this was the first time I elected applied to 2019 estimated tax.

Comment: Did you mean that your CPA filed it on 4/10/*2019*?

Comment: Yes, it should be.

Comment: You already have a CPA, why don't you just ask them?

Comment: Unless something has changed in the recent tax bill, you don't apply it to a quarterly payment.  It applies to the whole amount due.  Say for instance you have a $1000 refund, and would ordinarily pay $750/quarter estimated tax.  You could pay $500/quarter, or nothing the first quarter, $500 the second, or shift the payments to the last quarters...